# Is there a word for the process of giving a name or label for a concept?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, idiom-meaning

I'm looking to know if there is a word for naming things like in the examples below:

- Instead of saying "the tendency of people to accept evidence to their ideas and disregard the ones that disprove them", I can sum up this behavior as "confirmation bias". Now when I say the phrase "confirmation bias", everyone who knows it will understand what I mean.
- Or if I invent a sauce that everyone likes it, instead of asking "hey, have you tried this white sauce I made, it has eggs, mustard, lemon juice... and goes well on everything", I just call it "mayonnaise". So everyone can differentiate it from "hollandaise".

So if I'm thinking of a new name for a concept - how do I call this process of selecting a name? I'm thinking along "The Mental Model of " , but not sure if "naming" or "coining terms" is good enough...

Comment: You "coin" a ***new*** word. If you don't like transitive "name" for the act of bestowing a name on something, consider (sometimes slightly metaphorical and/or facetious) "**christen**". Or even more metaphorical "**dub**".

Comment: You could be *branding* the new item.